# Neo4j merge nodes with relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have got a question how I can merge the nodes for Documents (Doc1, Doc2 and Doc3), to get nice 3 start schemas.

```
for index, row in import_ds.iterrows():
     ind = ind+1
     graph.cypher.execute("MERGE (Document:Document"+str(fnum)+" {Document:\"Doc"+str(fnum)+"\"})")
     graph.cypher.execute("MERGE (Type:Type {Type:\""+str(row['type'])+"\"})<-[:HAS_TYPE]-(Word:Word {Word:\""+str(row['token_low'])+"\"})-[:IS_IN]->(Document:Document"+str(fnum)+" {Document:\"Doc"+str(fnum)+"\"})")

(WordType)<-[:HAS_TYPE]-(Word)-[:IS_IN]->(Document) http://www.yottalabs.co.uk/ss.png
[code output - Neo4j browser][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use parameters, not string substitution
2. merge tries to find the whole path, if it doesn't it creates the whole path

Usually you would merge the nodes first then the rels:

```
MERGE (type:Type {Type: {type}})
MERGE (word:Word {Word:{token_low}})
MERGE (document:Document {Document:{doc}})
MERGE (type)<-[:HAS_TYPE]-(word)
MERGE (word)-[:IS_IN]->(document)
```

#### Merge data on document node

```
MERGE (document:Document {Document:{doc}})
SET document.foo = {new_data}.foo, document.bar = {param_bar}
```

Comment: It's still separated (http://www.yottalabs.co.uk/ss.png) :( Is there a chance to load in as separated triples and then merge the Document nodes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can merge the data on the document node